# How to write business logic in a service as sinon in ExpressJS

Tags: express, mongoose, tdd, bdd, sinon

I want to use sinon to write test code for the business logic of a service using ExpressJS and Mongoose.

I wrote the following test code, but `findOneService` takes only id as an argument and returns a document with that id.

```
//service_test.js

const sinon = require('sinon');
// Service
const { findOneService } = require('../services/service');

// Schema
const Post = require('../models/mongoose/schemas/post');

describe('findOneService', () => {
    let find;

    beforeEach(() => {
        find = sinon.stub(Post, 'findOne');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        find.restore();
    });

    it('should findOne', async () => {
        const id = ???;

        ...?
    });
})
```

```
//service.js

exports.findOneDocument = async (id) => {
    const result = await Post.findOne({_id: id});

    if (!result) {
        throw new Error('404');
    }

    return result;
};
```

How can I define the result of this to pass the test code?

Answer (score 0):

To test this kind of behaviour, I strongly suggest an integration test (with an embedded/dockerized MongoDB, for example). This would allow to test-drive more things than just the service, such as schema, migration, db config.

However, if you just want to test-drive the `if (!result)...` logic, you can stick with sinon. What you're missing is stubbing the return value:

```js
it('returns the document if found', async () => {
  find.returns('a post');
  expect(await findOneService.findOneDocument('id')).toReturn('a post');
});

it('throw error when document does not exist', async () => {
  find.returns(null);
  expect(() => await findOneService.findOneDocument('non-existent id')).toThrow(Error);
});
```